# Mysql Login - Select Clause

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to mysql so any help would be appreciated.
I have written the following function to pull the user ID from a database where the email and password match, but it doesn't work.  If I put in my info it returns a user ID of 0, my user ID is 19.

```
function correctPassword($db, $userID, $password){
    $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM event_user WHERE user_email = '$userID' AND   user_password  = md5('$password')";
    $_SESSION['userId'] = mysql_query($sql, $db);
    if ($_SESSION['userId'] != 0)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

Any suggestions from you pros?

Comment: MD5 function is not called properly

Comment: Now that you are starting to learn Mysql, I highly recommend you to learn how to use Prepared Statements from the beginning. By using mysql_ functions you can leave your application open to SQL injections. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/ .

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function correctPassword($db, $userID, $password){
    $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM event_user WHERE user_email = '$userID' AND   user_password = '" . md5($password) . "'";
    $_SESSION['userId'] = mysql_query($sql, $db);
    if ($_SESSION['userId'] != 0)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: This is similar to what I had except for a change in calling md5.  I have tried this and I still get a user ID of 0.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: are the passwords salted? is the user id really the user email? is the return of mysql_query an integer? you are asking does the result of mysql_query != 0. it probably does not return just the result but a resource that wraps the result. try var_dump(mysql_query($sql, $db)); what do you see?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by salted.  The userID is in fact an email address.

Comment: when you insert passwords into the database you take the hash of the password plus some other known value. Long story short if someone manages to get a copy of your database they can not look at the hashs and compare them to a list of known word hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Add a connection in that function,also mysql_query returns a resource type so you can`t put that in `SESSION`.

```
function correctPassword($db, $userID, $password){
    global $db;
    $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM event_user WHERE user_email = '$userID' AND   user_password = '" . md5('$password') . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
      $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
      $_SESSION['userId']=$row['userId'];
    if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Ignoring the SQL doctor ready for an injection.

Comment: what do you mean by connection?  $db connects me to my database.

Comment: The variable where host,user,password is,something like $blah=mysql_connect(blah....)

Comment: that's what $db does for me.

Answer (score 0):

Some common errors I have made in this kind of code are:

1) Not starting the session with `session_start()`.

2) Not escaping single quotes. MySQL hates single quotes and would not mind breaking your query if it finds one.